# add custom column in active model serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, active-model-serializers

I use **active model serializers** to set my json output data in REST API, response just like following data.

```
{
  "articles": [
    {
      "id": 20,
      "show_map": true,
      "tag": {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Fake Atticle"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 19,
      "show_map": true,
      "tag": {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Fake Atticle"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

It's fine, but I want to add some custom data before my data, something like:

```
{
  "msg": "done",
  "status": "ok",
  "articles": [
    {
      "id": 20,
      "show_map": true,
      "tag": {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Fake Atticle"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't know how to do, i tried some ways, but no one can match what I want. I tried respond_with, render :json, .to_json...

and most important, I want it could be a common solution/method for all api, so I try to write method in my application_controller.rb:

```
def send_json(data)

    render :json => { 
      result: "200", 
      msg: "qq", 
      data: data }
end
```

but in this way, my serializers setting are all **useless**, it will render all column in my database...

what is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

you can render like this

```
render json: data,
       message: 'done',
       status: 200,
       serializer: ::SerializerName, root: true
```